# how to install mysql module using nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was not able to install the mysql module using the npm install mysql command on the nodejs command prompt in windows 8. Also i tried to install in the same directory from where i would run my main program

Comment: What was the problem that you ran into? Any stack traces? Error messages? Being specific about such things will help others to resolve your problem faster

Comment: You could also make a `package.json` file and just use `npm install`. On a side note, I suggest using a noSQL (mongodb, mongoose) database with node—it's so much better.

Answer (score 0):

first of all goto your nodejs installation directory using command prompt, I think it may be at C:\program files\nodejs 
try bellowed cmd

```
  npm install mysql
```

One more things you install into folder which does not have whitespaces in the path